# Keyboard and power button not responding but computer continues to work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hardware-failure

I have an issue with my ASUS K501UX laptop (running Windows 10) where all of the sudden, my computer keyboard as well as the power button stop working. The first time it happened to me I had the reflex to start again my computer (Windows → Restart). The computer powered off but not back on. Moreover I couldn't turn on again because the power button was not responding. After some time the computer power button worked again and I could turn in on again, no problem anymore after that.

For context, some months ago I went to a repair shop to fix the alimentation socket so it may have a link?  I don't intend on going back there again because I don't trust the shop.

Today it happened again. Except that I didn't touch anything and wait maybe 10 minutes, after this lap of time the keyboard restarted to function normally.

The computer is perfectly usable during the moment that the issues happened.
I am quite confused because it seems like a hardware issue, but if so, why does it work again after some time.

Finally it is super hard to troubleshoot because it only happens every X days for some minutes.

Comment: By “alimentation socket” do you mean power socket?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a dirty/blocked/failing fan. A suggestion would be to check the temperature of the processor. There are various apps out there for that.
Good Luck!

trembuzz

Comment: I'll try that next time I have this issue! Thanks for the message :)

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard and the power button under most circumstances should not lock-you-out! A quick isolation test: disconnect from internet, shut off WiFi, and wait for the problem to happen again; does it? If No, then some questions, [1] is this a work-pc potentially part of a domain? If yes, contact corporate Tech Support, if No, then [2] might the repair shop have installed a remote control app to assist you, like SolarWinds Dameware (Solarwinds was recently [Q4 2020] in the news for being hacked) or TeamViewer or Royal TS? I don't want to alarm you, but this link to discovering clues to *intrusion* might be helpful: https://www.wikihow.com/Detect-a-Remote-Access-to-My-Computer ;

Comment: Thank you, I'll try isolation test next time! [1] It is a personal device, not part of a domain [2] Thank you very much, I am currently checking carefully the link you told me and running malwarebytes as well as doing what they advise to do. I may put another comment if something comes up